# Extending a type does not seem to add all of its properties and functions

Tags: typescript, inheritance, mongoose, schema

I am extending the mongoose `Document` class with my own new class `ThreadDoc`. I am adding additional fields into my class, but would like to keep the fields of `Document`, which is why I am extending it. When I attempt to create a mongoose schema object I get an error on my generic that:

> Type ThreadDoc does not satisfy the constraint Document. ThreadDoc is missing the following properties

and then it goes on to list some like `increment`, `model`, `isDeleted`, etc. When I look at the constraint for `Model` it looks for `T extends Document` so I don't understand what the issue is.

I've tried switching the way I create my class by trying to create an interface instead, which for me does not work since I need to instantiate this type in my tests later, and extending an interface with my new fields, but can't get the error to go away.

```
// This is my current attempt at the class
export class ThreadDoc extends Document{
  threadTitle: String;
  threadBody: String;
  points: Number;
  bounty: Decimal128;
  createdBy: String;
  createdOn: Date;
  lastModifiedBy: String;
  lastModifiedOn: Date;

  constructor(
threadTitle: String,
threadBody: String,
points: Number,
bounty: Decimal128,
createdBy: String,
createdOn: Date,
lastModifiedBy: String,
lastModifiedOn: Date
  ) {
    super();

this.threadTitle = threadTitle;
this.threadBody = threadBody;
this.points = points;
this.bounty = bounty;
this.createdBy = createdBy;
this.createdOn = createdOn;
this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
this.lastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
  }
}

// then I call it like this
export const Thread: Model<ThreadDoc> = model<ThreadDoc>(
  "Thread",
  ThreadSchema
);
```

I get the errors on both references of the `ThreadDoc`. This is confusing to me because if I extend `Document` don't I necessarily inherit `Document`'s properties and functions? Why does mongoose not recognize this? From the original error I thought it only took `Document` as a generic type. But that's not true it takes anything that extends `Document`. So why does this code not work?

Comment: try [`MongooseDocument`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/v4/index.d.ts#L1030) instead of [`Document`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/v4/index.d.ts#L2702)?

Comment: Just tried same errors. I think this issue is not a bug. I'm just not understanding something about how extends works in typescript.

Comment: Well a `class` cannot extend an `interface`, only another `class`. It can _implement_ `Document` though, and then you can implement all the missing properties that exist in the interfaces that `Document` extends once you change `extends` to `implements` and get rid of the call to `super()`.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that Document implements an interface and it is those properties that are missing. Can you provide a document link for the interface and its details?

Comment: No, `Document` _extends_ multiple interfaces. I sent you a link to the type definition for it that you're referencing, you should be able to locate them through there. Once you make the changes I suggested, `tsc` should also report the missing properties and their respective types you need to implement on `ThreadDoc` as well.